# Calculating number of a specific substring from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string where I put all the characters read from a considerably large (500MB) text file. How I read the .txt file is given below.

```
    long fsize(FILE *fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long bytes = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    return bytes;
}
char *filecontent='\0';
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(file.txt,"r");
long size = fsize(fp);
fcontent = malloc(size);
fread(fcontent, 1, size, fp);     

`
```

**fcontent** points to the string which should be in following format :

```
matrix
trivial
bigbash
tropical
swalloed
.
.
.
```

Now I need to count the number occurrence of a substring say 'ba' from **fcontent**. As each line in the text file contains a single word and the substring search should be limited to that word only, How do I only select matrix, trivial, bigbash ... one word at a time from the **fcontent**?

Comment: Do you need an algorithm or do you need code? If the latter, what algorithm do you want the code to implement? If the former, could you give us a better idea where you're stuck on coming up with an algorithm?

Comment: I need code to isolate each word from the main string (fcontent) seuentially untill the last word is read. 
if I could do that, I could use C strstr(word_string, key) to search for the substring.

Comment: Okay, and do you have an algorithm for doing that? Or not? Before you write code, you have to decide what algorithm the code will implement. If you have an algorithm share it. If not, I'll suggest an algorithm for you. But it will be more useful to you if you choose the algorithm if you can. There are many ways you could do this. (For example, you could replace line endings with word endings. But that won't work if you need the line endings intact for subsequent operations.)

Comment: I don't have an algorithm. Can you share one?

Comment: @H.Jamil Might i ask what you want to do with the words that contain the substring? What about the other words ... are they garbage?

Comment: @Swordfish I need to check all the words where the substring may have found. Actually, I need to count the number of presence of the substring in the string.

Comment: @H.Jamil And what happens with the data when you are done counting?

Comment: @Swordfish that data (the original string ) needs to be unchanged for future processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm for you:

1. Have a current pointer. Initialize it to point to the beginning of the string.
2. Search from the current pointer for the first end of line character.
3. If you run off the end of the string, stop, you are done.
4. Convert the end of line character to a zero byte.
5. Process the string beginning at the current pointer.
6. Set the current pointer equal to point to the end of line character your replaced with a zero byte.
7. Restore the end of line character at the current pointer so that you don't damage the string (unless you don't care).
8. Keep incrementing the current pointer until it points to something other than an end of line character. If you hit a zero byte, stop, you are done.
9. Go to step 2.

Comment: How should I check if I run off the end of a string? Should I count the string length to do so?

Comment: @H.Jamil If you encounter a zero byte, you've reached the end of the string. If you encounter a '\r' or '\n', you've reached the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Your file consists of one word per line.  You read the entire file in then seek to break the resulting string by linebreak.

The far easier process is to read the file line by line using getline().

Then use strstr to search for your substring in each word.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/